# Find a sequence of same value in a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to check if a condition happened in the previous N rows of a dataframe column with the same value. What is the best way to do that?

Examples:

```
                              previous N columns  current column
                                   |  |  |  |  |  |
dataframe['condition'] = [F, F, F, T, T, T, T, T, F]
dataframe['operator']  = [F, F, F, F, T, T, F, F, F]
                                      ^  ^
```

I need to know if in the rows before the current one where condition is (T)rue if there was any operator that is also (T)rue.

In the example above the check would be true. however, if the columns are as below it should be False:

```
dataframe['condition'] = [F, F, F, T, T, T, T, T, F]
dataframe['operator']  = [F, F, F, F, F, F, F, F, F]
```

UPDATE!

I have realized my post was not clear enough and I apologize for that. What I would like to see as the output on both cases above:

```
dataframe['condition'] = [F, F, F, T, T, T, T, T, F]
dataframe['operator']  = [F, F, F, F, T, T, F, F, F]
dataframe['result']    = [F, F, F, F, F, F, F, F, T]

dataframe['condition'] = [F, F, F, T, T, T, T, T, F]
dataframe['operator']  = [F, F, F, F, F, F, F, F, F]
dataframe['result']    = [F, F, F, F, F, F, F, F, F]
```

and a bit longer example:

```
dataframe['condition'] = [F, F, F, T, T, T, F, F, F, T, T, T, T, T, F]
dataframe['operator']  = [F, F, F, T, F, F, F, F, F, F, F, T, T, F, F]
dataframe['result']    = [F, F, F, F, F, F, T, F, F, F, F, F, F, F, T]
```

Comment: what is the current position? is it always the last row?

Comment: I don't think OP wants a fixed check but rather all previous True rows for any False position

Comment: An example with more stretches of T/F and the explicit output would be helpful.

Comment: @It_is_Chris  It is always the last row. rows keep being added.

Comment: @adsjr is any of the answers working as you want? If not can you update the example to show a non working case?

Comment: @mozway please check the updated post.

Answer (score 1):

```
# your sample data
dataframe = pd.DataFrame()
dataframe['condition'] = ['F', 'F', 'F', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'F']
dataframe['operator']  = ['F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'T', 'T', 'F', 'F', 'F']

n = 5 # set the number of rows to look back
current_pos = 8 # the index of the current position
# use .iloc to filter to current position and tail to look back n rows
dataframe.iloc[:current_pos, 1].tail(n).isin(['T']).any() # -> True
```

Comment: This would not give me the result. This only tells me that there is at least one row True in the condition column. I need to know on the last rows where condition True is there was an operator True as well.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you need to use "condition" to define the range of rows to check. For this you need a `groupby`.

```
# group by stretched of T followed by F
g = (~dataframe['condition'][::-1]).cumsum()


dataframe['result'] = (dataframe
                        # is there any T among the corresponding operators?
                        .groupby(g)['operator']
                        .transform(lambda x: x.iloc[:-1].any())
                        # flag only last value of group
                        .mask(dataframe['condition'], False)
                       )
```

Output case 1:

```
   condition  operator  result
0      False     False   False
1      False     False   False
2      False     False   False
3       True     False   False
4       True      True   False
5       True      True   False
6       True     False   False
7       True     False   False
8      False     False    True
```

Output case 2:

```
   condition  operator  result
0      False     False   False
1      False     False   False
2      False     False   False
3       True     False   False
4       True     False   False
5       True     False   False
6       True     False   False
7       True     False   False
8      False     False   False
```

Output case 3:

```
    condition  operator  result
0       False     False   False
1       False     False   False
2       False     False   False
3        True      True   False
4        True     False   False
5        True     False   False
6       False     False    True
7       False     False   False
8       False     False   False
9        True     False   False
10       True     False   False
11       True      True   False
12       True      True   False
13       True     False   False
14      False     False    True
```

##### visual output (■ = True / □ = False):

```
# case 1
condition  □ □ □ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ □
operator   □ □ □ □ ■ ■ □ □ □
result     □ □ □ □ □ □ □ □ ■

# case 2
condition  □ □ □ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ □
operator   □ □ □ □ □ □ □ □ □
result     □ □ □ □ □ □ □ □ □

# case 3
condition  □ □ □ ■ ■ ■ □ □ □ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ □
operator   □ □ □ ■ □ □ □ □ □ □ □ ■ ■ □ □
result     □ □ □ □ □ □ ■ □ □ □ □ □ □ □ ■
```

Comment: That is not what I am looking for. I updated the post in order to make it more clear.

Comment: @adsjr I think my code gives you the correct output (result2), let me refactor for clarity